# Replacing a word over many files using Vim's regex does not work as expected in sed

Tags: vim, sed

I'm trying to use regex to substitute a word over many files that contain code. I don't understand regex very well, but I can get the desired effect in one file using Vim with the following command:

`:%s/\<Cat\>/Dog/g`

So, for example, using this in Vim would substitute, for example `(Cat, Cats) Cat,somethingelse, Cat.blah` with

```
(Dog, Cats) Dog,somethingelse, Dog.blah
```

Which is exactly what I want!

However, if I apply the same regex expression using `sed` (which I think is ultimately what I need to use to replace over many files) I get for example:

```
$ line="(Cat, Cats) Cat,somethingelse, Cat.blah"
$ echo "$line" | sed -n "s/\<Cat\>/Dog/p"
(Dog, Cats) Cat,somethingelse, Cat.blah
```

Which is the wrong output!

So my main question is: how do I obtain the effect I want outside of Vim. (Secondary question is: why are these behaviors different in the first place?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the modifiers wrong for `sed` to achieve the desired effect. The `-n` and `/p` are not quite correct in this context. You should have used

```sh
sed 's/\<Cat\>/Dog/g'
```

to achieve the equivalent of Vim's `:%s/\<Cat\>/Dog/g` command.

The `/g` modifier has an effect of substituting all matching fields, i.e. to replace multiple occurrences of source string with the replacement string. The `-n` and `/p` flags are used in `sed` for a [conditional print](https://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html#toc-uh-15) logic i.e. print the line if a pattern `Cat` is found.

Also note that, you can still use `-n` and `/p` with `/g`. But one key difference, is if the source string is not present, nothing is printed to standard output. But the same doesn't happen without it and you just see an unmodified string printed.

See

```sh
echo "$line" | sed 's/\<foo\>/Dog/g'
(Cat, Cats) Cat,somethingelse, Cat.blah
```

and below produces no output

```sh
echo "$line" | sed -n 's/\<foo\>/Dog/gp'
```

Comment: Oh I see. Seems very silly of me in hindsight. Thanks!

Comment: I know. I had to wait a few minutes to accept the answer